# Component Services - Enable partitions - Disabled

Tags: windows-7, com+

We just purchased new HP Z200 machines that came with Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit on them and we have upgraded them to Service Pack 1.

When we go into Component Services and expand computers and right-click on My Computer and choose properties, the Options tab has a disabled "Enable partitions" option that we have not been able to figure out how to enable.

We do not have this issue on Windows 2008.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a601d45a-10c0-4da9-a424-d35afef22161/how-to-enable-windows-7-windows-8-com-partitions-function

I'll quote in it's entirity:

> According to the Product team on this behavior, starting from Windows
>   Vista, they have the “Enable Partitions” checkbox grayed out on client
>   desktops. This was an intentional change as they want the ability to
>   have COM+ partitions to be available only on servers and not client
>   desktops.

...which makes me wonder why the blazes the checkbox is there in the first place if there's never going to be a way to enabled it.